# Ajax check if result is json or not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am Facing a small trouble..
I have a code which a ajax posts and returns a value from a page.
And the result is JSON , made by using

```
json_encode($response);
```

in **PHP**.

I converts the json to array using `jQuery.parseJSON` in jquery..
And it still works..
But sometimes it may happen any errors in my PHP page, So it will do not return a JSON code.
So the jquery shows error in `jQuery.parseJSON`.. 
Any Solution ??

Comment: Google: [Ajax check if result is json or not](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ajax+check+if+result+is+json+or+not)

Comment: Please say me your jquery version

Comment: What kind of errors? You can return errors and error messages through json just as well as results.

Comment: @Harutyun : response is array, and i use jquery 1.11.0

Comment: @jeroen : DB errors , and other errors

Comment: @ShameelKadannamanna As long as there are no syntax errors, you can catch almost all run-time errors and send the appropriate responses through json.

Comment: ok , can you write a code to catch these errors